# TypeORM opening too many connections in cron job

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I'm using `TypeORM` to query a database every minute. It seems each request opens a new connection/pool of connections on each request.

My cron job calls the method below.

```
export async function getBookings(): Promise<Array<$TODO>> {
  try {
    const db = await connection();
    const data = db.query(`...SQL QUERY...`)
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

The connection is as below. My assumptions here is that the check for existing connection should use an existing connection and not create a new one, however after a few minutes I have dozens of connections open.

```
export default async (): Promise<Connection> => {
  const manager = getConnectionManager();
  if (manager.has(config.name)) {
    const connection = manager.get(config.name);
    logger.info(`Connection manager has connection ${config.name}`);
    if (connection.isConnected) {
      logger.info(`Connection manager has connected connection ${config.name}`);
      return Promise.resolve(getConnection(config.name));
    }
    logger.info(
      `Connection manager reconnecting existing connection ${config.name}`
    );
    return await connection.connect();
  }
  logger.info(`Connection creating new connection ${config.name}`);
  return createConnection(config);
};
```

How can I ensure only one or a limited number of connections are open?